# How to pull changes from Developer Org when using Salesforce DX CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

How do I push and pull changes to a Developer Org using Salesforce DX CLI?

When I used this command:

```
sfdx force:source:pull
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: 
>   MemberName, IsNameObsolete FROM SourceMember WHERE RevisionNum
>
> ERROR at Row:1:Column:52
>   sObject type 'SourceMember' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Winter 19 release has pilot  commands to help with non scratch orgs.

You will need sfdx client pre release plugin installed to try .

The commands are

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -- retrieves metadata from the org using package.xml or metadata folder or comma separated list of metadata 

sfdx force:source:deploy -- deploy metadata to the non scratch org
```

To get started follow the instructions [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_sf_cli.htm)

**Install the Pre-Release Version of the CLI**

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
```

Make sure that you have the pre-release version.

```
sfdx plugins --core

salesforcedx 44.0.1-xx
```

> When the plugin is  officially released v44 in mid October 2018, uninstall the pre-release version, then run the update command.

```
sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx

sfdx update
```

Comment: That's good to know. It'll make migration a lot easier.

Comment: Do these commands in the pilot version work with v43 orgs, or only v44 pre-release?

Comment: All the orgs .It's based on metadata api .Org does not matter

Comment: @MohithShrivastava how do I access the pilot?

Comment: Updated the answer .Please check !!!

Answer (score 3):

`force:source:pull` is used to pull from scratch org only.

To 'pull' from developer org you need to use metadata API.

Use the `force:mdapi:retrieve` command.

For more info:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm

Comment: Thanks. I'd recommend reading this help with formatting answers :) 

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help